# How to create events lasting for a specified duration of time in AnyLogic

Tags: javascript, anylogic, modeling, discrete

I’m currently building a discrete event model where I’m trying to simulate port operations. In my model, I am looking to conduct “disruptions” using Event block. However, I couldn’t seem to find a way to specifically say how long the duration of the event ie the disruption will last. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

to create disruptions you might want to use the downtime block if your disruptions are resource related.

If you want to use an event object to create a disruption for a particular amount of time, you might want to evaluate using dynamic events if you have multiple disruptions for different objects in your model

Otherwise you can use an event with mode "user control" and when you want to schedule a disruption, you can do:

```
event.restart(amountOfTime, TIME_UNIT);
```

the time units are for example HOUR, SECOND, YEAR etc
you can look at all the existent units in the help documentation